# Is there a way to pass an html link using a TSQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have looked fairly extensively on the web, but haven't been able to find I have a query that I'm trying to write which passes values to an html table for email output. For one of the columns, I want to pass a link. Is there a way to do that? I'm currently getting an error saying 
`"Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '<a href="http://testServer/webnow/index.jsp?action=filter&username=anonymous&drawer=AP-General&folder=' to data type int."`

See the snippet of code below.

```
SET @Body = COALESCE(@Body + '', '') + 
    CAST((SELECT DISTINCT Api.GLAccountID, 
        api.CostCenterNumber,
        api.VendorNumber, 
        --SPECIFICALLY THIS LINE...
        '<a href="http://testServer/webnow/index.jsp?action=filter&username=anonymous&drawer=AP-General&folder=' + v.VendorID + '&tab=' + api.Invoice + '">' + api.Invoice + '</a>'
    FROM dummytable api
    FOR XML RAW('TR'), ELEMENTS) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '</TABLE>'
```

Comment: Common error.  Convert INTs to varchar when using them to build a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the value for `v.VendorID` is of the type `INT`. Looking at the other fields (`v.VendorID`, etc ..) they may also be of the type `INT` or `NUMERIC` so I have also casted them as `VARCHAR`, you may want to play around with the size of the datatypes.

This should help:

```
SET @Body = COALESCE(@Body + '', '') + 
    CAST((SELECT DISTINCT Api.GLAccountID, 
        api.CostCenterNumber,
        api.VendorNumber, 
        --SPECIFICALLY THIS LINE...
        '<a href="http://testServer/webnow/index.jsp?action=filter&username=anonymous&drawer=AP-General&folder=' + CAST(v.VendorID AS VARCHAR(50)) + '&tab=' + CAST(api.Invoice AS VARCHAR(50)) + '">' + CAST(api.Invoice AS VARCHAR(50)) + '</a>'
    FROM dummytable api
    FOR XML RAW('TR'), ELEMENTS) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '</TABLE>'
```